# Laravel eloquent use scope in accessor

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I try to create an eloquent accessor which depends on a few conditions:

```
public function getStatusTypeAttribute()
{
  if($this->new) {
    return 'NEW';
  }

  if( ! $this->new && $this->active && $this->customer_choose) {
    return 'PLANNED';
  }

  if( ! $this->new && $this->active && ! $this->sent_to_customer) {
    return 'ACCEPTED';
  }

  return 'OLD';
}
```

I have a few more conditions, which i also want to access separate (say i want only the newly items. So i try to add scope methods like:

```
public function scopeNew($query)
{
  return $query->where('new', true);
}
```

Now i can access them via `$model->new()->get()`, but i cant get it work for the accessor:

```
public function getStatusTypeAttribute()
{
  if($this->new()) {
    return 'NEW';
  }

  ...
}
```

dont work. He gives me for every item the `status_type` of NEW, even though the `new` attribute is on `false`.

Comment: You can't do so. The scope is a query builder it works to add conditions or other functionality to your query before send the query to database.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `if ($this->new)` in the accessor, you're actually checking if model's property `true` or `false`, so it doesn't make any sense to use a scope here.

Also, a scope is a filter for the query and accessor is a method that uses one object, so you'll not be able to do anything like this anyway. Use simple methods if you want to reuse some code.

Comment: Yeah, but i want to use the scope inside my accessor, so i dont need to define them twice (for every condition).

Comment: @nutzt the point is, even if you could use the scope inside the accessor, it literally doesn't make any sense since `if ($this->new)` and `if ($this->new())` is the same in terms or brevity, readability etc. Also, you can't do it anyway, so if you want to reuse some parts of the accessor, move the code to a method and use it from as many accessors as you like.